# Harden a public login to only let it retrieve a list of other logins, and do nothing else

Tags: sql-server, security

I'd like my app's login dialog to give users a drop-down-list of login names on the server. So I'm wondering about the most secure way to retrieve this.

The best I can come up with is a login with a hardcoded password that can only access a stored procedure that'll return a list of other logins. What's the best way to harden this? I would love to create a login trigger that'll return what I want and then force the connection to close, or a trigger that will run for all statements, but this doesn't look possible..

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Will it be possible for users to try and make a connection to SQL server outside of your application? For example, is something stopping your users from opening up Excel and directly connecting to the SQL server?

Comment: Just be aware showing a list of usernames is a security no-no.  Giving away the usernames halves the necessary work to break into the system.

Comment: This is a really bad idea - as Max said, it's a security no-no - it is more than 1/2 of the work as even if only one user has a weak password, you have provided hackers with a list to try against.  If you insist on doing this, please post the site so I can be sure to not use it.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2008 R2. The app is a windows desktop app that accesses SQL server via an intranet. I realise it'd be more secure to not give away usernames, but I have to think about usability too. I think the usernames won't be that hard to guess, and aren't even "***"-out when being entered.

Answer (score 2):

"Most secure" is an ambiguous statement that needs more explanation. You need to think about what kind of attack vectors you are trying to mitigate.

For example, what if a malicious user trys to brute-force your built-in account? It's going to be locked out. This creates a denial of service scenario, as normal users cannot receive a list of valid accounts either. If you were trying to mitigate a DoS scenario by using hard-to-guess logon names, you just shoot your own foot.

Hard-coding a password in your application will make it insecure. First, it can be extracted from the application, no matter how you encrypt it. That's exactly the way Blu-Ray encryption was broken. Second, should you need to change the password, you need to ship new binaries to all the users which is somewhat a hassle.

How about creating a SSIS package that publishes a list of valid logins on a network share? This moves some security configuration from the database to your AD group membership maintenance.

Comment: +1 for defense in depth idea of last sentence - at least user needs to gain access to AD to get list of usernames.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The usernames won't be hard to guess, and I can disable lockout against the hardcoded login-discovery account. I realise its password can be easily extracted, that's why I'm trying to lock down the login-discovery account as much as possible.

Comment: A network share is a good idea, but I fear it'll be quite burdensome to set up, this app gets distributed to customers via an install package. I don't really want to assume their AD is working properly either.